# District maps in tableau is not displaying

Tags: tableau-api

[image: **enter image description here**]

strong text

I want to create District Maps in tableu.
Districts are from States in India.

I don't know how to make it correct.

Can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: Don't forget that even if Tableau doesn't have built-in maps for the areas you want to use, you can always just find some standard spatial maps and add those to tableau as a data source (kml, ESRI or mapinfo maps all work, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creating a hierarchy does not work, I would recommend taking a particular city in the district and creating visualizations off of that as a proxy for the district. Or you could take the postal codes to do so as well. I haven't seen your data so I do not know what is possible for you. However, you could also run geo-spatial scripts in the Tableau environment to create the map yourself instead of relying on the Tableau interface.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/qs_hierarchies.htm

https://www.mapsofindia.com/districts-india/